# How can I display an object which I had pushed using react into firebase back in the screen? How could the objects in firebase be deleted?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to React and Firebase. I'm trying to display the object newData as mentioned in the code. I've pushed in a value but later it shows the error in the screen attached.

[image]

I'm creating a menu app so I want to add menu into the firebase and also in the mean time return the current menu as well. How could I return from the firebase? How can I update or delete the data already present in the object in firebase? Is there any way to access an object that I had uploaded before? Suppose I push a menu with dishes and price and then how could I delete it or update it. (each specific dish)
Image of the database is attached.

[image]

componentWillMount(){
        /* Create reference to messages in Firebase Database */

```
    let messagesRef = fire.database().ref('vendor/'+this.state.Day+'/'+this.state.Vendor+'/dishname').orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
    messagesRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
      /* Update React   state when message is added at Firebase Database */
      let message1 = { text: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
      this.setState({ messages: [message1].concat(this.state.messages) });
    })
  }
  addMessage(e){
    let messagesR = fire.database().ref('vendor/'+this.state.Day+'/'+this.state.Vendor+'/dishname').orderByKey().limitToLast(100);
    messagesR.on('child_added', snapshot => {
      /* Update React   state when message is added at Firebase Database */
      let message1 = { text: snapshot.val(), id: snapshot.key };
      this.setState({ messages: [message1].concat(this.state.messages) });
    })

    var newData={
    Type: this.inputE3.value,
    Dish: this.inputEl.value,
    Price : this.inputE2.value
    }

    fire.database().ref('vendor/'+this.state.Day+'/'+this.state.Vendor+'/dishname').push(newData);
    this.inputEl.value = ''; 
  this.inputE2.value = ''; 
  this.inputE3.value = ''; 

  }
```

Comment: Did you read the firebase documentation?

Comment: Yes I did I'm not sure on how to get back the object that's pushed

Comment: There should be a callback that you can use and it has a snapshot of the updated or newly added document

Comment: Can you plese point it out ? I'm new to this.

Comment: Do you have a repo that I can use to investigate this?

Comment: https://github.com/jobymathew/Foodhub_Web/tree/master/src - Please find the code in Vendor.js file

Comment: Okay cool. Will have a look at it

Comment: Thanks I'll wait for your update

Comment: Hi, do you got any updates cause I'm really in a situation right now :(